# Can I create my own digital certificate in C# or Windows?

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I'm working on C# win app about digital signature..

I knew how to import and export both the private and public key using "x509certificate2" class in C# (I'm exporting private key in PFX type is that right ?)

The problem is how to create a digital certificate?

How to obtain one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

- [How to: Obtain an X.509 Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819929.aspx)
- [Makecert.exe (Certificate Creation Tool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

I prefer a tool written by the guys over at plural sight. It allows you to make a cert and store it directly into the windows key store of your choice or a pfx file. It is all GUI based and a lot easier to work with then make cert.

http://blog.pluralsight.com/selfcert-create-a-self-signed-certificate-interactively-gui-or-programmatically-in-net

Comment: @RogerLipscombe You can find it now at http://blog.pluralsight.com/2012/02/13/selfcert-create-a-self-signed-certificate-interactively-gui-or-programmatically-in-net/ I also edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: The pluralsight tool is quite nice!

Comment: Fixed dead link to save others the search.